# Workaround for using function from context hook outside a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, toast

I understand that we cannot use hooks outside a component, but was looking for a workaround of using function from context hook outside a react component to show toast (using a separate utility function).

Saw usage of event emitters for achieving this but wanted to explore some another workaround if its there.
[Creating A React Component That Can Be Shown With A Function Call (like react-toastify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67443376/creating-a-react-component-that-can-be-shown-with-a-function-call-like-react-to)

```
export const useToast = () => React.useContext(ToastContext);
```

and

```
const { add } = useToast();
```

Basically, want to use this function from context outside a component.

Comment: Is a viable solution to export the `showToastNotification` in its bare form for usage outside of the `useToast()` hook, and only leverage it with the hook form from inside a component?